# Removing content existing in another file in bash

Tags: linux, bash, awk, grep

I am attempting to clean one file1.txt that contains always the same lines using file2.txt that contains a list of IP addresses I want to remove. 
The working script I have written I believe can be enhanced somehow to be faster in execution.

My script:

```
#!/bin/bash
IFS=$'\n'
for i in $(cat file1.txt); do
        for j in $(cat file2); do
                echo ${i} | grep -v ${j}
        done
done
```

I have tested the script with the following data set:

```
Amount of lines in file1.txt = 10,000
Amount of lines in file2.txt = 3

Scrit execution time: 
real    0m31.236s
user    0m0.820s
sys     0m6.816s
```

file1.txt content:

```
I3fSgGYBCBKtvxTb9EMz,1.1.2.3,45,This IP belongs to office space,1539760501,https://myoffice.com
I3fSgGYBCBKtvxTb9EMz,1.2.2.3,45,This IP belongs to office space,1539760502,https://myoffice.com
I3fSgGYBCBKtvxTb9EMz,1.3.2.3,45,This IP belongs to office space,1539760503,https://myoffice.com
I3fSgGYBCBKtvxTb9EMz,1.4.2.3,45,This IP belongs to office space,1539760504,https://myoffice.com
I3fSgGYBCBKtvxTb9EMz,1.5.2.3,45,This IP belongs to office space,1539760505,https://myoffice.com
... lots of other lines in the same format
I3fSgGYBCBKtvxTb9EMz,4.1.2.3,45,This IP belongs to office space,1539760501,https://myoffice.com
```

file2.txt content:

```
1.1.2.3
1.2.2.3
... lots of other IPs here
1.2.3.9
```

How can I improve those timings?
I am confident that the files will grow over time. In my case I will run the script every hour from cron, therefore I would like to improve here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to get rid of all lines in `file1.txt` that contains substrings which match `file2.txt`. [grep](/questions/tagged/grep) to the rescue

```
grep -vFwf file2.txt file1.txt
```

The `-w` is need to avoid that `11.11.11.11` matches `111.11.11.111`

> **`-F, --fixed-strings, --fixed-regexp`** Interpret `PATTERN` as a list of fixed strings, separated by newlines, any of which is to be matched.  (`-F` is specified by POSIX, `--fixed-regexp` is an obsoleted alias, please do not use it in new scripts.)
>
> **`-f FILE, --file=FILE`** Obtain patterns from `FILE`, one per line.  The empty file contains zero patterns and therefore matches nothing.  (`-f` is specified by POSIX.)
>
> **`-w, --word-regexp`** Select only those lines containing matches that form whole words.  The test is that the matching substring must either be at the beginning of the line or preceded by a non-word constituent character.  Similarly, it must be either at the end of the line or followed by a non-word constituent character.  Word-constituent characters are letters, digits, and the underscore.
>
> **<sub>source: `man grep`</sub>**

---

On a further note, here are a couple of pointers for your script:

1. Don't use for loops to read files (http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor).
2. Don't use `cat` (See [How can I read a file (data stream, variable) line-by-line (and/or field-by-field)?](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001))
3. Use quotes! (See [Bash and Quotes](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes))

This allows us to rewrite it as:

```
#!/bin/bash
while IFS=$'\n' read -r i; do
  while IFS=$'\n' read -r j; do
      echo "$i" | grep -v "$j"
  done < file2
done < file1
```

Now the problem is that you read `file2` N times. Where `N` is the number of lines of `file1`. This is not really efficient. And luckily [grep](/questions/tagged/grep) has the solution for us (see top).

Comment: Amazing, I was not aware of that!

Comment: @creed I have updated the command. Be aware of the `-w` flag, it is needed!

Comment: The while improvement is a great tip. I will stop using for.